# Bind TextBlock's Text to the SeletedItem text of a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a ListBox that I provide with `DisplayMemberPath` in run time, and have a `TextBlock` that I want its Text property to be bound to the  selected item text of the ListBox, hardcoding the value works:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBx, Path=SelectedItem.Title}"/>
```

But how I do it without knowing which property is used for displaying?

**Edit**

The `ListBox` and the `TextBlock` are parts of the `ControlTemplate` of a custom control that has a custom `DisplayMemberPath` property that I bind to the listBox's `DisplayMemberPath`

```
    <ListBox Name="lstBx" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource}" 
DisplayMemberPath="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DisplayMemberPath}" 
SelectedValuePath="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedValuePath}"/>
```

Comment: @Mohammed Ahmed can you be more clear what you meant by _But how I do it without knowing which property is used for displaying?_

Comment: see the edit please

Comment: If none of the answers (that seem plausible here) work for you, you must provide an MCVE to show your effort & the real problem. Otherwise this is ripe for closing.

Comment: I don't think using SelectedValue for that matter or overriding the ToString method for every class used in the ItemsSource are plausible solutions

Comment: Also I provided the MCVE question that you marked as duplicated as I can't delete this question because it has answers, and can't modify because the answers are based on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you have 2 options:

1. create your own extension of Listbox. which has a kind of `SelectedDisplay` property (it should work like `SelectedValue` property, but using `DisplayMemberPath` instead of `SelectedValuePath`)
2. use a `MultiBinding` and some lamba expression dynimic building.

I will show you the second solution. First of all the multibinding:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource PropertyMultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="lstBx" Path="SelectedItem"/>
            <Binding ElementName="lstBx" Path="DisplayMemberPath" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Now the code for the `PropertyMultiValueConverter` class (of course it can be improved and optimized for avoiding a continuos lambda expression generation):

```
public class PropertyMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object selectedItem = values[0];
        string displayMemberPath = values[1] as string;

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            ParameterExpression param =
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(selectedItem.GetType(), "x");
            MemberExpression body =
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(param, displayMemberPath);

            LambdaExpression lambda =
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(body, param);

            Delegate expression = lambda.Compile();
            return expression.DynamicInvoke(selectedItem);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Lambda expressions are faster than using reflection, so I prefer this way. As you can see the generated lambda expression retrieves the value of the property and returns it.

Comment: But `SelectedValue` is not aimed to serve this purpose, to my knowledge it provides a value to use for other operations, I need the UI representation of the Text from the ListBox, also I may set the SelectedValue to `Id` for example

Comment: @MohamedAhmed, what do you mean with "the UI representation of the Text from the Listbox"? I understood you want to display a property of the selected item without knowing that property (since it can be retrived from a binding). For example you want to display the `Title` property: in this case `SelectedValuePath` should be set to `Title`, and `SelectedValue` will show exaclty the value of that property.

Comment: I mean that I don't want to be forced to use SelectedValue for a display purpose, I may want to set it to be the Id of the selected item, while the DisplayMemberPath is set to the Title property

Comment: I see  your point of view @MohamedAhmed. Indeed I completely rewrote my answer. I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, It works like a charm.
and the code is less shorter and simpler than if I used Reflection,
I'm tying to understand how it works, where is the part that says: give me the property named `x` and where is the part that gets its value, 
and how any way expressions works with non-IQueryable objects,
I know this is beyond my question, but I'd be grateful if  you 
give an explanation?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed what I did is to build a lamba expression in a dynamic way (something like `x => x.Property`). It is a powerful tool! you can get more info to start [here on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079028/Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

I think i get your question. Seems you meant SelectedItem.{CanBeAnyProperty} right?

One solution could be you bind your textblock like below :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBx, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

And override SelectedItem ToString() method to return appropriate desired property value.

For example: say your Item bound to list is Person.

So you can override ToString() method of person class like :

```
class Person{

Public string ToString(){
return Name; /*this again you need to work out runtime* OR/
return Age.ToString();}
}
```

Comment: So, whenever I use class as an object for the ItemsSource I will need to override the ToString method?!.. No, I don't want this

Comment: I assumed model type which you binding to your list box is fixed. Do you mean you gonna bind your listBox for example with IEnumberable<Person> or IEnumerable<Student> at runtime ?

Comment: Yes, so simply I want to get the text (`Content`) of the `SelectItem` of the `ListBox`, regardless which type it represent, in XAML

Comment: ohk. Did you tried `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBx, Path=SelectedItem.Value}"/>` ?